# Java Security Warning window turn blank in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, applet

I just fresh install Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop few days ago and installing all applications that I need to work with. Everythings looks fine, until I find that I can't run any Java application using my web browser because Java Security Warning window turn blank. It's happen to all of my web browser (Firefox & Google Chrome).

[image: Blank Java Security Warning window]

Anyone have solution?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit with Oracle Java 7. Thanks and best regards.